# Motivation for Ionescu Tulcea-Marinescu (Lasota-Yorke inequality)

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, limit-theorems

I wonder about motivations of a work of [Ionescu Tulcea-Marinescu](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969514?origin=crossref#metadata_info_tab_contents). In order to establish the decomposition of the operator $T$ they assume (condition (1.3)) this operator satisfies the inequality

$$\|Tx\| \leq r.\|x\|+R.|x|$$

We find this type of inequality in the work of [Lasota-Yorke](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1973-186-00/S0002-9947-1973-0335758-1/home.html) as well. I wonder about the motivation of this inequality for Ionescu Tulcea-Marinescu.